# A problem of ending the implementation of the code

Tags: c++

this code works well for all samples, but after all samples are finished, a problem occurs. I don’t know what happens and the program crashes. Is there a problem with this code?
i have this problem when i use strings arrays usualy can it be the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
long long  t,n;
int a[1000];
string str[1000];
int main()
{
    cin>>t;
    for(int r=1;r<=t;r++){
      cin>>n;
      int maxi=0;
      for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
        if(a[i]>maxi)maxi=a[i];
      };
      //input first value
      maxi=maxi+3;
      for(int r1=0;r1<maxi;r1++){
        str[1][r1]=(rand()%26)+'a';
      }
      for(int i=0;i<maxi;i++){
              cout<<str[1][i];
      }
        cout<<endl;
      //
      for(int k=2;k<=(n+1);k++){
            int w;
            for(w=0 ; w<=a[k-1];w++){
                str[k][w]=str[k-1][w];
            };
            for(int l=w-1;l<maxi;l++){
                str[k][l]=(rand()%26)+'a';
            };
            for(int i=0;i<maxi;i++){
                cout<<str[k][i];
            }
            cout<<endl;
      }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do your program does? Also, show the input/output to produce the error.

Comment: You are using elements of strings without allocating them.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with the code. `<bits/stdc++.h>` is bad. Pairing it with other includes shows you're copy/pasting without knowing what you're copy/pasting. `using namespace std;` is a bad practice. There is literally no reason for those variables to be global. If you don't know what you're putting into  your own code, you are a victim of "cargo cult programming."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using elements of strings without allocating them.

Allocate elements by inserting

```
for(int i=1;i<=(n+1);i++){
    str[i].resize(maxi);
}
```

just after

```
maxi=maxi+3;
```

Comment: MikeCAT Thank you very much , it works perfectly now